# ¿Cómo obtener el dia del año a partir de una fecha seleccionada en un DatePickerDialog 1 - 365?

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente código

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(año, mes, dia);
num_dia = Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR;
String d = Integer.valueOf(num_dia).toString();
tvdias.setText(d);
```

Deseo obtener el día del año.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solo hay que hacer un pequeño cambio a tu código, para que se obtenga el valor

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(año,mes,dia);
 int num_dia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);// Aquí obtengo el dia del año
 String d = Integer.valueOf(num_dia).toString();
 tvdias.setText(d);
```